# My Android phone (HTC M8 Eye) is not connecting to the PC, it's only charging

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, htc

When connecting my phone to the computer via USB I get no indication of it being connected other than that it starts charging. Usually when I connect it shows the USB icon in the status bar and either goes into USB mass storage or debugging depending what I used when it was connected last and shows the status of the USB connection in the notification area.

I have read through multiple posts on multiple forums with problems like this and I have tried:

- rebooting the phone
- restarting my PC
- unmounting SD card
- unmounting SIM card
- using a different cable and usb ports

But nothing works. I think this problem happened after clearing all cache using CleanMaster but I'm not sure. Also I tried connecting another phone with the same cable and the phone was able to transfer files, so I think the problem is in my phone only.

Comment: See if this helps - enable developer options (settings > about phone > tap build number 7 times ) . In developer options > select USB configuration > select MTP

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the HTC drivers installed https://m.mediafire.com/folder/jgt1b5bc2stwf/Drivers